# JQuery equivalent of Node.js Step / Async modules

Tags: jquery, node.js, plugins, asynchronous

Do you know any JQuery plugin which is equivalent of Node.js Step or Async modules? Here are descriptions:

https://github.com/creationix/step/blob/master/README.markdown
https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks, I will look at my previous questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

jQuery has deferred execution in it's API. That's simply what step and async do. Use this.

Comment: It is good, but it can't be used as simple as Step. If I want to call more than two functions, I have to nest then() methods. I also have to use two methods for pair of functions...

Comment: @user744436 your looking for `$.when.apply($, arrayOfDeferreds)`

Answer (score 0):

Caolan McMahon has written [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library which can be used both in the browser and Node. This way you can share the same code if you want to switch from node <--> browser.